# How do I make a JPopupMenu appear when a JCheckBox is clicked?

Tags: java, swing, jcheckbox, jpopupmenu

I have a `JCheckBox` in a program (labeled "Use MiniTimer") that, when right-clicked, shows a `JPopupMenu` with options "Show on Close", "Show on Minimize", "Show on Close or Minimize", and "Do not use MiniTimer". How can I make this `JPopupMnu` appear below the `JCheckBox` when it is left-clicked, too?

Note that I tried setting the actionPerformed method of the `JCheckBox` to `miniTimerPopupMenu.setVisible(true);`, but that merel makes the `JPopupMenu` appear in the top-left corner of the screen, and even then, it will not register any interactions with it. Does anyone have any experience or suggestions they would like to share?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Bringing Up a Popup Menu](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html#popup) for a working example. The tutorial uses popup.show(...). Don't know if that is the difference.

If you need more help post your SSCCE (http://sscce.org) that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should set the location of the miniTimerPopupMenu using the setLocation() method, I think the following code does the trick

```
    miniTimerPopupMenu.setLocation((int)jCheckBox.getLocation().getX(),(int)jCheckBox.getLocation().getY()-10);
    miniTimerPopupMenu.setVisible(true);
```

Then you can play with y and x location of the top popupmenu.

Hope this works

Comment: I, in fact, did exactly that. It appears in the right place, but still, as I said in the question, it refuses to accept interactions.

Comment: if you mean adding action listener to popupMenu try this link http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/Addingactionlistenertopopupmenuitem.htm

Comment: no, all the actionListeners are there. It simply won't register that a mouse has entere, exited, clicked, hovered, or dragged within it. Nor will it register keystrokes.

Comment: Disregard that last comment. It seems to be working, now. Thank you!